# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSinkProvider. Please find packages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, mqtt, apache-bahir

I have added

```
"org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-mqtt" % "2.4.0"
```

to my `build.sbt`, and using

```
df
  .writeStream
  .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSinkProvider")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .option("topic", "mytopic")
  .option("brokerUrl", "tcp://localhost:1883")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination(20000)
```

in code, but getting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSinkProvider. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:679)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been realized that the reason of that behavior is usage of the wrong dependency `"org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-streaming-mqtt" % "2.4.0"` instead of `"org.apache.bahir" %% "spark-sql-streaming-mqtt" % "2.4.0"`

After repairing that I have faced the new issues